# Skype For Business Online Authentication Error - 403 Permission Denied

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, ucwa

Hello Microsoft/Azure/Skype experts,

I'm tasked with accessing presence data from Skype For Business Online accounts from my macOS app (native).
I'm unfortunately stuck and i always get a 403 error when i access the autodiscover request  and never get the link to the applications resource

I have been following this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread

**STEP 1**
  We have registered the app in the Azure Management Portal using our Office 365 account credentials.

- We have used custome redirect URL (http://localhost)
- Allow Implicit Flow is set to true in manifest
- We pre-configure the permissions needed for Skype for business
  online 
  [image]

**STEP 2**
Issuing a GET as specified in the documentation to initiate sign in and authorization check.

> GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=c#####-4d41-485e-871f-0a22aa79e52b&redirect_uri=http://localhost

This returns a 200 OK.

**STEP 3**
We got the Auto discover URL as described in the documentation.
This is what i get - i use the domain marked in RED.
[image]

**STEP 4**
As per the documentation, they ask me to do this

*Requesting an access token using implicit grant flow*
So i issue a GET as described

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/authorize?
>   response_type=id_token &client_id=######-4d41-485e-871f-0a22aa79e52b
>   &redirect_uri=http://localhost
>   &state=8f0f4eff-360f-4c50-acf0-99cf8174a58b
>   &resource=https://webdirin1.online.lync.com

Now this shows the sign in page, i sign in and then it throws an error

```
AADSTS90014%3a+The+required+field+%27nonce%27+is+missing.
```

I researched and could not fix this error.
So after lots of research and looking at this Microsoft documentation LINK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent) , apparently  there is another way of getting the bearer token.

**STEP 4 - SECOND TRY**

I then Request individual user consent by sending the SCOPE parameter for Skype for Business.
I then issue a GET request to

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=#######-4d41-485e-871f-0a22aa79e52b&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_mode=query&scope=https://api.skypeforbusiness.com/User.ReadWrite&state=12345

This returns an access code which i use in next step to get the TOKEN

**STEP 5 - Get the bearer TOKEN**

Issue a POST to following URL
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token With the
following data in POST body

> "grant_type": "authorization_code", "client_id":
>   "######-4d41-485e-871f-0a22aa79e52b", "scope":
>   "https://api.skypeforbusiness.com/User.ReadWrite", "code":
>   "OAQABAAIAAACEfexX.........", "redirect_uri": "https://localhost"

This returns the bearer token in the following response JSON

```
{
"access_token" = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1........w4b--    gnWG_iOGtQ";
"expires_in" = 3599;
"ext_expires_in" = 3599;
scope = "https://api.skypeforbusiness.com/User.ReadWrite";
"token_type" = Bearer;
}
```

**STEP 6**

Yay! Got the bearer token at laaast!
Now back to the main documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread

And where we do this - 'Resending an autodiscovery request with the bearer token'
We execute a GET request to

> https://webdirin1.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user

Now this, as per the documentation should return this JSON

```
{
            "_links":{
            "self": 
     {"href":"https://webdirX.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/user"},
         "applications": 
        {"href":"https://webpoolXY.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications"}
         }
         }
```

**BUT i GET A 403: PERMISSIONS denied error**

```
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
 <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
 <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page 
  using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
```

So thus i have never got the applications url and I have checked the manifest, registration and i have no idea, why i get this error.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: For step 4, you need to specify `nonce=somestring` in the URL. Typically this should be a securely random value that is only used once. It can contain any value.

Comment: @junnas has a good suggestion.. additionally, I see that after Step 4 you have switched to using `v2.0` endpoint to get token. Don't mix up the endpoints, and continue using the same one as documentation suggested as it's related to how you registered your application in first place.

Comment: @juunas Thanks that helped solve the error - but i get an id_token as a response and dont get the access_token and if use that i still get 403 error

Comment: You are only requesting an id token. Set `response_type=id_token+token`.

Comment: @juunas Thank you.  That solved it, am able to get the application URL.  It's incredible that MS documentation does not mention the options you told me. 
But now i need to POST to the applications URL and i get a "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." Do i need to send the same access token? I will keep trying.  You have been very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Okay that sounds like more of a problem with Skype's API. A 502 is usually a kind of a connection problem. Yeah the docs could be clearer on the possible params.

Comment: @juunas Thanks Juunas - The issue is resolved.  You can mention your response as the answer - specify nonce=somestring in the URL & response_type=id_token+token 

I will MARK as Answer.

Comment: @kamyFC Sir.. Please answer my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170656/skype-for-business-receive-im-not-working-with-the-below-steps ..  I am not able to receive im, in skype for business UCWA api. As you have already worked on this, I am not able to receive any IM in UCWA.  Please guide me sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For step 4, you need to specify `nonce=somestring` in the URL. Typically this should be a securely random value that is only used once. It can contain any value.

Also, you are only requesting an id token. Set `response_type=id_token+token`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @juunas Sir.. Please answer my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170656/skype-for-business-receive-im-not-working-with-the-below-steps ..  I am not able to receive im, in skype for business UCWA api. As you have already worked on this, I am not able to receive any IM in UCWA.  Please guide me sir.